# How do I write this JSTL for loop in JSP? Unable to find unambiguous method: class java.lang.Math.min(Long, Integer)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, jstl

I have the following:

```
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="${Math.max(1,page-5)}" end="${Math.min(page+5,pages)}">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="?page=${i}">${i+1}</a>
    </c:forEach>
```

It gives the error

> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Unable to find unambiguous method: class java.lang.Math.min(java.lang.Long, java.lang.Integer)

If I try to manually cast them to `(int)`, then it gives a different error!

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [528], column: [2]) [${Math.min((int)(page+5),(int)pages)}] contains invalid expression(s): [javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${Math.min((int)(page+5),(int)pages)}]]

I also tried

```
<% for (int i=Math.max(1,${page}-5); i<Math.min(${page}+5,${pages}); i++) { %>
```

But Eclipse couldn't parse it.

Comment: Since `pages` is type `Integer`, try `end="${Math.min(page+5,pages.longValue())}"`

Comment: can you not just calculate the values in the controller and add to model?

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, that did work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pageNo` variable name instead of `page`. The variable name `page` is the issue. For example, the following works:

```
<c:set var="pageNo" value="3"/>
<c:set var="pageCount" value="6"/>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="${Math.max(1, pageNo-5)}" end="${Math.min(pageNo+5, pageCount)}">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="?pageNo=${i}">${i+1}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

The output shows each number as a link (with HTML `<a/>` tags): 2 3 4 5 6 7

**EDIT**: Note from the JSP 2.0 specification: "The variable name `page` is of type `java.lang.Object` and described as: The instance of this page’s implementation class processing the current request page scope". It is one of the *Implicit Objects* available in JSP pages.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, but I think I forgot to mention I'm using Spring Boot and at the bottom of the controller method is `return new ModelAndView("displayUrls").addObject("page", page).addObject("pages", pages);` So it seems to override (or shadow-scope) the JSP `page`.